# Is Not StartsWith(Mozilla) enough to identify most bot UserAgents w/o affecting any real visitors?

Tags: asp.net, user-agent, bots

I am trying to not do some session initialization routines for bots on my asp.net pages. Thus I am thinking of a test like:

```
bool IsBot = !(UserAgent.StartsWith("Mozilla") || UserAgent.Contains("Opera"));
```

Is it enough? Any additional recommendations? Would it work properly in 99% of the cases?

Comment: Wouldn't this identity older versions of IE as bots?

Comment: IMO every properly coded bot will send a valid UserAgent string. So I think this check will only sort out those which are very low in quality...

Comment: I don't know, that's why I am asking. I would like a definitive answer that will list major cases where this test will fail and affect real users.

Comment: @PilgerstorferFranz The matter is not whether they send a non-empty UserAgent string. The matter is that I don;t want to manually maintain a huge list of all possible bot names (that would be valid UserAgent strings).

Comment: What about using a captcha or a [reCaptcha](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/index.html) I think this would sort out 99% of bots

Comment: @PilgerstorferFranz It has to be a purely programmatic check w/o UI involved. I need this to decide on SessionStart how I will "treat" such a user, thus I cannot afford to deal with captchas.

Comment: I think if you just have to rely on the very first http GET Request there is no way to verify if the user is human or a bot. You need at least some kind of user interaction (eg reCaptcha). In theory you could check for some queryString param - which in return would have to be dynamically generated ...

Comment: Most legitimate bots provide an URL in there user-agent eg:
Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm) 
Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)
Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; GimmeUSAbot/1.0; +http://gimmeusa-update.com/crawler so you could check whether the agent contains http://. That isn''t 100% but it works for most

Comment: @Luc Excellent suggestion! How confident are you it will not affect legitimate users? That is - is it possible that some legitimately browsing users would have UserAgent string containing "http://"?

Comment: By default a user agent doens't contain "http://", it is possible for a user the change the user agent, but a user who does that knows that this might have consequences for a webpage

Comment: @mason I checked and it looks like all IE versions all the way back to v. 6 start with Mozilla string so why would this be an issue for older IEs?

Comment: Okay, maybe it's not an issue for IE. But it's possible there are other browsers out there that don't start with Mozilla or Opera.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, based on my research, I think the following will suffice:

```
Private _Bots As String() = New String() {"bot", "slurp", "crawl", "spider", "sleuth", "http://", "https://"}

Public Function IsBot(aRequest As HttpRequest) As Boolean
    If aRequest.Browser.Crawler Then Return True
    Dim _ua As String = aRequest.UserAgent.ToLower
    If Not (_ua.Contains("mozilla") OrElse _ua.Contains("opera")) Then Return True
    For i = 0 To _Bots.Length - 1
        If _ua.Contains(_Bots(i)) Then Return True
    Next
    Return False
End Function
```